# How to constrain saving id number as a value of field in ManyToOne Doctrine relation?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have ManyToOne relation defined below.

Persisting owning side object, with inversed object setted in there, resulting in saving row in db of owning side where column that I expect to have value of *id* foreign key (integer) instead it save *name* (string) field of inversed table side.

In other words:

column iptra_documents.document_category_id contains value from iptra_document_category.name. I'm **expecting** to have iptra_document_category.id value in iptra_documents.document_category_id

Owning side:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="iptra_documents")
 */
class IptraDocuments
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="document_id", type="integer", unique=true)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $documentId;

    /**
     * @var IptraDocumentCategory
     * @ORM\Column(name="document_category_id")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\IptraDocumentCategory", inversedBy="id")})
     */
    private $documentCategory;
    //.....
    public function setCategory(IptraDocumentCategory $documentCategory)
    {
        $this->documentCategory = $documentCategory;
    }
```

Inverse side:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="iptra_document_category")
 */
class IptraDocumentCategory
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="parent_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $parentId;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\IptraDocuments", mappedBy="documentCategory")
     */
    private $iptraDocuments;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional), you don't need `@ORM\Column` but `@ORM\JoinColumn` to define "Many" side

```
/**
 * @var IptraDocumentCategory
 *
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\IptraDocumentCategory", inversedBy="id")})
 */
private $documentCategory;
```

Comment: it helps, it helps!